# Instagram style news feed logic

Tags: feed

I am in the process of making a social application that involves users and a news feed. In order to display a user's news feed in chronological order, which of the following would make more sense?

1. Get all posts from each user the person is following and sort them into chronological order
2. Each time a user goes to post, save that id and the date into each
   of their followers profile data (seems redundant)
3. A better solution that you may know

Comment: Hello Matt, Have you found any solution to this? Or Have you get any info related to this topic?

Answer (score 0):

Generally social sites are built using Graph Database. I have worked on one of the social sites. Below was the technology stack and logic to display the news feeds.

1. Java, Spring MVC
2. OrientDb- A GraphDB containing Vertex connected with Edges
3. JQuery & Bootstrap for UI
4. Apache Solr- for text searches on User,Articles

Below was the logic for newsFeeds:

1. When any user does any activity, we used to create Activity vertex containing 
   the meta-data of activity like dateTime, type of activity and actor etc.
2. We had a batch program(running after every 3 mins) which will go thr all unprocessed the activities. The onus of the batch is to generate the newsFeeds from Activity and assign these **newFeeds_To_Be_Displayed** to relevant users(i.e connections of actor) **newsFeeds to be displayed** on screen.
3. When the user logs in, we used to query newFeeds_To_Be_Displayed of the given user and display them on screen.

We chose to calculate the **newFeeds_To_Be_Displayed** asynchronously, as thats a time consuming process and we dint want to end up in bad user experience.

Comment: How would this approach work when loading more content after the current content has all been viewed? Also, I am looking for a more streamlined approach where I can quickly determine which posts should be displayed in a chronological order. This is a lot of data to pull so I wanted to find out if there was a good way to organize this for quickly determining the order

Comment: If you make this newsFeeds_To_Be displayed as an ArrayList, it will be in chronological order. Also, you can have separate List read & unread newsFeeds to be displayed, whenever the ui pulls the unreadNewsFeeds, move the items in that list to readNewsFeeds.The batch job will add more newsFeeds in UnreadnewsFeeds.